# What is the best practice to save data object in database from android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I am newbie in `Android` development and learning best practice. I create an `Android application` having two modules

- App
- Facebook-lib

I have already added the `dependencies` of `faebook-lib` in `App` module gradle.

```
 compile project (':facebook-lib')
```

My activity flow:

Splash Screen

check if I the app has `Facebook access token` or not

If not then move to `Facebook activity` in `Facebook-lib` module.

Everything works fine from getting `Token` to `User ID` but I want to save this user information in database residing in `Parse.com`. What would be the possible solution here?

1. How about If I create a new model/pojo `UserInfo` Singleton class in `App` module. Access it from `facebook-lib` module and then save into `Parse` database. If yes, then I am not able to access model class from `facebook-lib` module.
2. I can't even access `custom class` extended by `Application` in `facebook-lib` module.

Can you guys please suggest some best ways to solve above problem?

Comment: You're generating `Access Token` in your by using `Facebook-lib` So you can store this `Token` in `Application` level in your App. Why would you want to store in `Facbook-lib`?

Comment: @MD yes I can but the problem is I am not able to access the class extend by `Applicaiton` in `Facebook-lib` module. I haven't added `App` module dependencies in `Facebook-lib` gradle.

Comment: No. you dont understand my point.  Why you want to store `token` in `Facbook-lib`?

Comment: Not necessary. BTW I am not storing `token` in `Facebook-lib`. I created this module only to keep some methods separate like `getUserName` or `getDOB` from `Facebook Access Token`. Also the `Facebook` activity is in the same module. But I am calling this `FacebookActivity`  from `App` module.  Did I give answer of  your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply use shared preferences:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit(); 
 editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore); 
 editor.commit();
```

See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html